# unable to merge dex. Tried everything still not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried with:
1)Clean and rebuild.
2)multiDexEnabled true.

But still the error shown is:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Any suggestions how to fix it, please help ?

My app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.facebook_login"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.33.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My project level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    //for Facebook SDK
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
   }
   allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: sometimes it comes from manifest merging , or AAPT failures , or 3rd party library failures

Comment: add the full stack trace of gradle error , you can find that in gradle console or in newer android studio in build tab

Comment: Did you try disabling `Instant Run` in Android Studio? And check your `AndroidManifest.xml` if there any error.

Comment: When I tried to run the emulator , then only the mergeDex error appears otherwise when I build the error is not displayed. @KooroshGhorbani you may be correct, so what is the solution?

Comment: No @Shashanth, where can we disable that from?

Comment: hey I am getting this mergeDex error in all of my projects on running the emulator

Comment: In Android Studio `File` - `Settings` - `Build, Execution, Deployment` - `Instant Run` just uncheck `Enable Instant Run..`

Comment: i think it comes from your gradle , try to reinstall gradle , disable instant run , and try again

Answer (score -1):

Adding these few lines helped remove the error successfully for me :
Here is the new app level gradle file, you can compare and find the changes.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.mkchat"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1-beta1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```